# View Multiple Model that JOIN with FK through query from Controller

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is Controller Code

```
    //Approved
                public ActionResult Approved(String VoucherNIK, String Admin, int? month, int? Year, int? minPrice, int? maxPrice)
                {
                    if (Session["Nama_Lengkap"] != null)
                    {
                        var NIKLst = new List<int>();

                        var NIKQry = from d in db.Voucher
                                     where d.Voucher_Number >= 2000
                                     orderby d.NIK
                                     select d.NIK;
                        var query = from app in db.Approved
                                    join det in db.Detail on app.ID_Approved equals det.ID_Approve
                                    join vou in db.Voucher on det.ID_Voucher equals vou.ID_Voucher
                                    join adm in db.Admin on app.ID_Admin equals adm.ID_Admin
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        vou.NIK,
                                        app.Tanggal_Approve,
                                        app.Total,
                                        app.ID_Admin,
                                        adm.Nama_Lengkap,
                                        app.ID_Approved
                                    };
                        IEnumerable < int > enumerable = NIKQry.GroupBy(v => v).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
                        NIKLst = enumerable.ToList();

                        ViewBag.VoucherNIK = new SelectList(NIKLst);

                        try
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Admin))
                            {
                                query = query.Where(s => s.Nama_Lengkap.Contains(Admin));
                            }

                        }
                        catch (DataException /* dex */)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to Apply.");
                        }
                        return View(query));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                    }
                }
```

And the View

```
        @model IEnumerable<Voucher.Models.Approved>
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Approved";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Approved", "Voucher", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    NIK Voucher       :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("VoucherNIK", null, "All") <!-- new { onchange = "document.location.href = '?VoucherNIK=' + this.value;" })!-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    ADMIN Approve     :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("Admin")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Month             :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("month")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Year              :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("Year")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Price(min NUMBER) :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("minPrice")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Price(max NUMBER) :
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("maxPrice")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn-toolbar" /><br />
        }

        <br />
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Nama Admin
                </th>
                <th>
                    ID Approved
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tanggal
                </th>
                <th>
                    ID Admin
                </th>
                <th>
                    TOTAL
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nama_Lengkap)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Approved)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tanggal_Approve)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Admin)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("More Detail", "DetailAppr", new { id = item.ID_Approved })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

When Run i got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1
>   ,but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[MvcMarks.Models.MarksType]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return` statement to

```
 return View(query
                 .Select(it => new MarksType{
                     //initilize properties of `MarksType` with `it`     
                 }));
```

Your view expects a model of type `IEnumerable<MarksType>` but `query` variable is `IEnumerable` of [Anonymous objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).